# Visual Studio tool - Copy several lines of code and paste as one - remove new lines from clipboard

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, line, copy-paste

I'm working on a big C# project which is terribly formatted. Let's say I have block of code on several lines, I want to convert it to one line, without deleting blank spaces manually.

**Example:**

Console
                .

```
WriteLine
            ("Products: " +
                           products)
            ;
```

And I want to convert it **to this:**

```
Console.WriteLine("Products: " + products);
```

Is there some kind of tool out there, that could work for me - for example, cutting the badly formatted code with **Cntr + X** and pasting it on one line with overridden combination e.g. **Cntr + Shift + V**?

As far as I've read, you cannot adjust those settings manually in windows, so I figured some kind of tool would be needed.

Comment: You could select the text, press CTRL+H (search and replace), change it to Regex and replace `\r\n` with empty string? CTRL+K, CTRL+D should handle it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Visual studio auto formatter?! Ctrl + K + D 
Also you can try Resharper to Clean and format the code. You can use the trail version.

Comment: Visual studio's Ctrl + K + D doesn't help much in this scenario, but resharper's format selection tool is just what I needed. Thanks a million!